# STM32F407ZET6, Is it possible for Multiple streams of a DMA to run in Parallel?

Tags: dma, stm32f4discovery, stm32f7, stm32cubeide

Hi I am using STM32F407ZET6 Microcontroller and I want to use multiple streams of DMA1. Is it possible to trigger two different streams of the same DMA for transferring data to two different peripherals simulatenously. (Like in Parallel).

In the advanced AHB bus matrix I observe that for each DMA there are only two lines, one for memory and one for peripheral, which suggest to me that at any time at max two streams can perhaps run in parallel and that also if none of the streams are really doing **memory<->peripheral** transfer. Is this assumption correct? And, is this also correct that to run two streams in parallel through a single DMA they should not be doing **memory<->peripheral** transfer? what I mean is that by the look of AHB matrix it felt if only Mem to Mem and Periph to Periph transfers are done then probably two streams can run in parallel, but if any one of them does **memory<->peripheral** transfer then the use of DMA memory and peripheral interface for a single transfer will probably make that **NOT** possible. Can you shed some light on this?

I would like to request some guidance on this particular topic as i could not find satisfactory information on it... And if it is dependent on the bus bandwidth to transfer streams in parallel then how the bandwidth is divided among multiple channels for a single bus to perform multiple transfer.... Some If there is any such example, i would be thankful. As a reference I have put the AHB matrix below:

[image]

Comment: Learn the difference between 'parallel' and 'concurrent'.  Typically main memory is single-ported, and can only perform one access (either a read or a write operation) at a time.  A single-ported memory obviously cannot support parallel accesses.

Comment: If you closely look at the bus matrix then you will realize that we have segments of memory here each with its own access line. They are also distinctly connected to different ports of DMAx's and CPU. For example, if CPU is fetching data from CCMRAM or even SRAM1 then SRAM2 can very well be used by DMAx's to do transfer in parallel once triggered... 

So, I understood very well that its possible to simultaneously trigger multiple streams of a DMA but of course they get scheduled. However, a DMA can still run in parallel with CPU accessing another segment of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only select one channel per stream, but you can enable all 8 streams per DMA peripheral at once if you like, subject to the hardware defect listed in the errata sheet*.

Each of the masters take turns to access the buses.  Once a master takes the bus it decides how long to use it for.  For the DMA master, this is configured with the MBURST and PBURST bits of the DMA_SxCR register.  If you require very low latency in the system and do not want the processor or another master (ethernet etc) to be stalled and have to wait for the DMA to get off the bus then set the burst configuration short (but even the longest burst you can configure will still only be a microsecond or so).

(*) there is a hardware defect in DMA2 which disallows concurrent use of AHB and APB peripherals, see [the errata](https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/dm00037591-stm32f405407xx-and-stm32f415417xx-device-limitations-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for details.

Comment: I was trying to use i2c and ADC on the same DMA (different channels). Separately it works, but when I put both in the same code I get errorHandler();